# Update 'Quantity On Hand' file import odoo 10e

Tags: odoo-10

Tried the following solutions

1. Import products with 'quantity on hand' as one can
   see in the [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q8eb4TmWrOlgSScExFvNyzs250pRz8SzwlQCNzemxms/edit?usp=sharing) import file. For quantity on hand added
   another column "Inventories/Checked Quantity" but it is not getting
   import.
2. There is a youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Obp3RO6Yp0) to import the 'Quantity on
   hand' by Inventory adjustment, tried this but not successful.
3. [Package](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/import_product_with_qty_on_hand/) may do the trick but it is only available for community addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity on hand value is not in the same table as product templates and product variants.

Only solution is to perform two separate imports:

1- Import product templates and variants

2-  Import an Inventory Adjustment

For second step import the file with fields (

```
  - Inventories/Checked Quantity          (Quantity on hand)
  - line_ids/location_id/id               (default value for all rows stock.stock_location_stock)
  - Inventories/Product                   (Product name)
  - Inventory Reference                   (Product name)
```

)

After import click on validate and save the file then click on the latest inventory item --> validate inventory